# To Inject bean reference to a job class in JobDetailBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler

I'm using spring batch along with quartz scheduler to trigger a job every 5 secs.

```
<bean name="JobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.batch.test.FirstJob" />
</bean>
```

Here instead of passing the class itself is it possible to pass reference of a bean?

```
<bean id="firstJob" class="com.batch.test.FirstJob">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"> </property>
    </bean>
<bean name="JobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
            <property name="jobClass" ref="firstJob" />
    </bean>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally came to know what has to be actually done.

```
<bean name="JobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass">
            <bean factory-bean="firstJob" factory-method="getClass"></bean>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Hope it'll be useful to someone someday :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It purely depends on your use case.

Consider the class below :

```
  public ClassA{

      private Class clazz;
      private FirstJob firstJob;

      public Class getClazz() {
          return clazz;
      }

      public void setClazz(Class clazz) {
          this.clazz = clazz;
      }

      public FirstJob getFirstJob() {
          return firstJob;
      }

      public void setFirstJob(FirstJob firstJob) {
         this.firstJob = firstJob;
      }
}
```

Dependency Injection:

```
 <bean id="firstJob" class="com.batch.test.FirstJob">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"> </property>
</bean>

<bean name="JobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="clazz" value="com.batch.test.FirstJob" />
        <property name="firstJob" ref="firstJob" />
</bean>
```

Comment: where would I refer this Class clazz?. Plus two properties of the JobA has the same FirstJob reference?